# homeomorphisms on k-spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let X be a Hausdorff k-space (Hausdorff compactly generated space) and h a bijection on X such that for any subset E of X we have

```
E compact <=> h(E) compact.
```

Question: Does it follow that h is a homeomorphism?  (The converse is true for any space X since the continuous image of a compactum is compact).

Background: I am trying to see if it is possible to define homeomorphisms on Hausdorff k-spaces solely in terms of preservation of compact sets.  More generally, I would like to identify topological spaces for which such a characterization of homeomorphisms would be possible.

Thanks, 
Pouya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If you restrict $h$ to any compact subset $E$, then $h$ gives a homeomorphism from $E$ to $h(E)$, because a subset of $E$ (or $h(E)$) is closed iff it is compact, so $h$ and its inverse both preserve closed sets.  By compact generation, this implies that both $h$ and its inverse are continuous, so $h$ is a homeomorphism on the whole space.

Comment: Thanks, in the meanwhile I made a very similar reasoning, which I post below (partly for my own reference; I tend to lose my notes).

Take any compactum $K \subset X$.  Then $h(K)$ is compact by assumption.  Thus any closed set $C\subset h(K)$ is also compact, being a closed subset of a compactum.  Therefore $h^{-1}(C)$ is compact, and hence closed ($X$ is Hausdorff).  Thus the pre-image of any closed set $C$ under $h|_K$ is closed, i.e. $h|_K$ is continuous.   By compact generation, $h$ itself is continuous.  Similarly, one shows that $h^{-1}$ is continuous, i.e.
$h$ is a homeomorphism.